# Natively showing different context menus in Listview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, contextmenu

Inheriting from ListView control for WinForms and I would like to display a context menu when a item is selected and a totally different one when there is none.

This approach seems straight forward and I saw lots of examples that basically listen to the right click event and upon that decide which context to show and force it to show at cursor location.

What I am looking for if there is a more efficient / native method of doing it rather than listening to the right click event, for starters it will not work if you try to open the context from the keyboard (either shift+F10 or with context key). Plus, if you are using keyboard to navigate the listview and your cursor is elsewhere then it looks horrible. On top of that the menu should be shown on mouseUp and not mouseDown which make it a bit more complicated.

I was looking for an event of the base control class that would handle the "onContextInvoked" or similar, even onContextOpening but at the control level not the context menu level.

Anyone has a better feedback/solution/approach to this?, or I just have to deal with mouse/key events and force to show a context which is not actually bounded to the control itself?

One idea I had is to always use one context menu as normal and then on the opening event of that one check if items are selected and if not try to cancel that context and open the other one on that very same position, but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Assign a `ContextMenuStrip` to the `ContextMenuStrip` property, handle its `Opening` event and populate it there based on appropriate criteria. You don't need two different menus. You can override the property so that it cannot be changed from outside.

Comment: Thanks @John I was also considering this option, but since the context menu have more than 50+ items I was trying to avoid removing/adding the items on opening stage.
If I understand you correctly that approach would involve hidding/showing the items based on whatever items are selected or not.